# WPF RadGridView Default Date Value to Empty Value

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

How to override telerik radgridview's default date value (1/1/1900) to empty in xaml

xaml binding is like :

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn  Header="Estimated Start On" DataMemberBinding="{Binding EstdStartDate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N2}"   Width="100"  IsFilterable="False" IsGroupable="False">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Content="{Binding EstdStartDate}" Height="30"    />
             </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Thanks,
Sarathi

Comment: Can you show what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on how to implement [WPF Value Converters](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/wpf-value-converters/).

VIEW:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding DateColumn, Converter={StaticResource MyDateConverter}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

CONVERTER:

```
public class MyDateConverter:IValueConverter  
{  
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime test = (DateTime) value;
            if (test.Year > 1900) // If year is greater than 1900 then display
            {
                string date = test.ToString("d/M/yyyy"); // Your date format
                return date;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }  

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
    {  
        throw new NotImplementedException();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Dear John, That one worked like a charm , and thanks for that link too.
Thanks for reading and answering, you are not like others who downvote the question when there is no sample code, even with out reading whats being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the default value. Here DateTime.MinValue is the default value

```
if (EndDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    Response.Write("Null");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but john given the useful one, please take a note on that